# Getting around rounding errors with floor of log in python

Tags: python, math, rounding-error

In order to find the number of digits of a number in a certain base, I attempted to write the line:

```
numdigits = math.floor(math.log(num, base)) + 1
```

where `math.log(num, base)` is equivalent to `math.log(num)/math.log(base)`

However in both cases, this will sometimes get the number of digits wrong. This is because the answer to math.log is a float, and therefore has limited precision. For example, when computing log base 3 of 3486784401 (3^20):

```
>>> math.log(3486784401, 3)
19.999999999999996
```

Taking the floor of this would give 19, whilst the correct answer is 20. I understand that this is because of the way floating point numbers are represented in binary, however I was wondering if there was a way around this issue.

Is there a way to write a function that gives the floor of a logarithm in any base, with 100% accuracy?

Comment: You can use `sympy.log` for exact computations.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko thanks! do you know how this works? and how fast it is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple ways.

1. You could evaluate the number of digits as you do in your question. Then you could *test* your result by calculating `base**result` (in integers so you get an exact result) and seeing how it compares to your original parameter. You adjust `result` up or down by 1 and test again until you are sure your final result is correct. You should need at most 3 tests.
2. Similarly, you could skip the `log` test and just evaluate powers of `base` until it reaches or exceeds your parameter. This keeps things completely in integers but would be more time-consuming.
3. Of course, another way is to actually do the conversion into the desired base, then check the number of digits. This is even more time-consuming, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Log division with `math.log10` does the trick:
[image]

```py
math.log10(3486784401)/math.log10(3)
// 20.0
```

I've no idea how.

### **UPDATE:**

This answer explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323713/2340227
Basically, `log` with no base arg in python is a natural logarithm (where base is a math constant *`e`*). `log` with a base argument is a division of two natural logarithms using logic illustrated on the picture above. Since *`e`* is imprecise (`2.71828...`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), it leads to rounding errors that are not present with log10 (which uses 10 as base).~~

### **UPDATE 2:**

The fact that the result was correct with `log10` is a pure fluke of how the rounding worked out. Using base 10 does not avoid rounding error, as you'll see with examples like math.log10(125) / math.log10(5). (If this actually avoided rounding error, math.log would simply do this internally.)

Comment: The fact that the result was correct here is a pure fluke of how the rounding worked out. Using base 10 does not avoid rounding error, as you'll see with examples like `math.log10(125) / math.log10(5)`. (If this actually avoided rounding error, `math.log` would simply do this internally.)

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for correcting me! Can you suggest a sure way to avoid rounding error?  
I guess we could just use python rounding function, duh

Comment: For the specific purpose of digit counting, as given in the question, the techniques in Rory Daulton's answer work. There's no good answer for general-purpose floating-point logarithms, though.