# Python math.log and math.log10 giving different results

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I was writing a code to calculate number of digits in a given whole number.

I was initially using

`math.log(num,10)`

but found out it was giving incorrect(approximate) value at num = 1000

```
math.log(1000,10)
>2.9999999999999996
```

I understand that the above might be due to the floating point arithmetic in computers being done differently but the same, however, works flawlessly using math.log10

```
math.log10(1000)
>3.0
```

Is it correct to assume that `log10` is more accurate than `log` and to use it wherever log base 10 is involved instead of going with the more generalized `log` function?

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python's math documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) specifically says:

> `math.log10(x)`
>
> Return the base-10 logarithm of x. This is usually more accurate than log(x, 10).

Answer (score 3):

According to the Python Math module documentation:

> `math.log(x,[base])`
> With one argument, return the natural logarithm of x (to base e).
> With two arguments, return the logarithm of x to the given base, **calculated as `log(x)/log(base)`.**

Whereas in the `math.log10` section:

> `math.log10(x)`
> Return the base-10 logarithm of x. **This is usually more accurate than `log(x, 10)`.**

It might be due to the rounding of the floating point numbers.

Because,
If I take the first method of using `log(1000)/log(10)`, I get:

```
>>> log(1000)
6.907755278982137
>>> log(10)
2.302585092994046
>>> 6.907755278982137/2.302585092994046
2.9999999999999996
```